# How to change the Lock screen custom text(Owner Info)?

Tags: android, security, settings, lockscreen

I wrote the program code

```
String message = "This is test";
            Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, message);
```

This is not changing the lock screen text(Owner Info)
and Added permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED` to `Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED`.

Note that `Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED` was deprecated in API level 21. You must use [getNextAlarmClock()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#getNextAlarmClock%28%29) instead. `getNextAlarmClock()` is a public method in 
*AlarmManager* class which was introduced in API level 21. You need to install *API level 21* in order to use this method. Also, make necessary changes in Android Project Build Target.

Comment: Settings.System.getNextAlarmClock() method is not shown in that package,which one i can use,please just check that package(Settings.System)

Comment: Please provide some code how to use getNextAlarmClock(),because in my program it is showing some error means it takes the AlarmManager class           but it is not getting AlarmClockInfo class

Comment: i am using target api level 20 only then i can use Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED,but this one is also not added custom text to lock screen

Comment: Have you installed API level 21? I updated the answer.

Comment: on which device you are testing?

Comment: Thanks it's working in motorola,but in my device it's not working why?  what is the difference between device support in this example

Comment: And i have one more doubt in lock the screen when i am click on the lock now button it will run devicePolicyManager.lockNow();   ,ok this is running in my device but some devices it is giving error like( Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10093)
this type of error ,How to rectify this error,the same code working in different devices but some devices it's not working.

Comment: I tested the code on Nexus 5 and Samsung S3, and its working fine. Regarding java.lang.SecurityException, I suggest you to ask another question for this to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving this better information