# Action of Notification and lock screen

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen

When my app receives some kind of information I show a notification on the lock screen. In the notification there is one action. When the user picks the action, I want to open an activity. To start the activity user should unlock the screen (a behavior I can accept). But The problem is that I want to show some kind of a message (at least a Toast) after the user picks the action. How can I do it?

Scenario:
1) The phone sleeps and the screen is locked
2) The app receives some info.
3) The app sends notification
4) Notification has action(button) "Do1"
5) User clicks by the button "Do1"
6) The phone asks the user to unlock the device.
7) User unlocks his device
8) The phone opens the activity

I want to show a toast after point (5) and before point (6).

Thanks.

Comment: before unlocking the device we can't make toast or any other messages, but when user unlocks the device then we can make toast message like after 7th step. and we can start our application activity when user unlocks the device by using Active user receiver.

Comment: you mean, after user unlocks the device you can start activity, but may be there is some way to show to the user a message that he should unlock the phone...

Comment: ha after unlocking device we can start our activity, and r u telling about ownerInfo , if it is owner info we can change the message of owner info from our program.

Comment: No, I didn't talk about owner Info

Comment: then until unlock we didn't show any message in user's device I think, just check once what is what? like which type of message if it like toast it is not possible.

Comment: What type of message it could be? I need to show a message to the user. I thought about Toast (not works), other activity or dialog (but I don't want to unlock the device programmatically, I want the user unlocks the device)..

Comment: yes when user unlocks the device after we start our activity and make in that a message like toast message or alert box anything after user unlocks the device based on the Active user Broadcast receiver.If you want this kind I will tell what to do.

Comment: Allu, big thanks, but I want before user unlocks the screen. After unlock I propose you use USER_PRESENT_ACTION, am I right?

Comment: yes you are right, If you want to write any message before unlocks I think one main way is OwnerInfo other than that no message is displayed in lock screen.

Comment: How can I do it? I found that owner info is readable only.

Comment: see this link you will get it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739066/how-to-change-the-lock-screen-custom-textowner-info