# How do you access Lock screen text settings on android in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, settings

On Android devices if you go to Settings -> Display -> Advanced -> Lock Screen
there is a field: "Add text on lock screen"
I need to access this field value in Xamarin, however am not finding any documentation anywhere on where this field is stored

Comment: do you have any reason to believe that Android offers an API to control this setting?

Comment: No I simply have the faith that if there is a setting on a device there is a way to access what that value is programmatically.... I don't need to write to it, I just need to read it...

I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739066/how-to-change-the-lock-screen-custom-textowner-info  which appears to be attempting what I am attempting via the post description however the answer is incorrect

Comment: Correction this field must be accessible,  we are using external software "workspace one" which updates this setting on all of our devices remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager manager = Android.App.Admin.DevicePolicyManager.FromContext(MainActivity.Instance);
var name = manager.DeviceOwnerLockScreenInfo.Trim();
```